# Removing a user from an arraylist by username

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I am using blueJ to write this. What I am trying to do is write a method called removeUser() in the userGroup class which takes a String as a parameter which is the username I want to remove. Using an Iterator, iterate over the list until I find the user with that username and remove them. My code is:

```
package user; 
public class User{
    public enum UserType{                          
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
    }

    private String id;                            
    private UserType userPermissions;              
    private String actualName;                     

    public User(String username, UserType userType, String name){
        id = username;
        userPermissions = userType;
        actualName= name;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType(){
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName(){
        return actualName;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType input){
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

and the userGroup class is:

```
package user;
import java.util.*;
import user.User.UserType; 

public class UserGroup{

    private ArrayList<User> people;

    public UserGroup(){
        people = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void addSampleData(){
        people.add(new User("jar1g13", UserType.ADMIN,"Jonny"));
        people.add(new User("ao9", UserType.EDITOR,"Aniruddh"));
        people.add(new User("pe6", UserType.USER,"Peter"));
        people.add(new User("mat73", UserType.USER,"Matthew"));
        people.add(new User("ora69", UserType.EDITOR,"Oranthi"));
        people.add(new User("ben12", UserType.USER,"Benedict"));
        people.add(new User("cam30", UserType.ADMIN,"Cambyse"));
        people.add(new User("are20", UserType.USER,"Alex"));
        people.add(new User("lim19", UserType.USER,"Liam"));
        people.add(new User("ada13", UserType.EDITOR,"Adam"));
    } 

    public User getUser(int idx){
        return people.get(idx);
    }

    public void printUsernames(){
        for (User user: people){
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getUserType());
        }
    }

    public void removeFirstUser(){
        people.remove(0);
    }

    public void removeLastUser(){
        people.remove(people.size()-1);
    }

    public void removeUser(String username){
        people.remove(username);
    }

}
```

This all compiles fine but when I run the removeUser method it doesn't seem to remove anything from the array!

Comment: The answer is in the question: *Using an Iterator, iterate over the list until I find the user with that username and remove them*. That's not what the code does. It tries to remove a string from a list of users. Do what the question says. And use consistent names for your variables: id or username, but not both. actualName or name, but not both. It makes things extremely confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void removeUser(String username) {
     Iterator<User> itr = people.iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()) {
          Users element = (User) itr.next();
          if (element.getUsername().equals(username)) {
               itr.remove(); // REMOVE THIS FROM Iterator
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: why compare string with == operator?

Comment: But it's still wrong. Test it, and see by yourself. You'll get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: True. Updated the code. Now it works correctly. Thanks for correcting!  Everydays a learning. :)

Comment: This  "if (element.getUsername().equals(username))" will have to replaced with "if (element.getUsername(). equalsIgnorcase(username))". Cheers.

Comment: @SathishJayapal: only if you want to ignore the case, which is not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove a User instead of a node with the string username, or if you really want to remove a user by a string, just iterate until you find a user with the same string, User.actualName.equals(username)

```
public void removeUser(String username) {
   Iterator<User> it = people.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()) {
   if(it.next().getName().equals(username)) { it.remove(); break; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a function. Say, `getUserByName(String name);`

As so:

```
public User getUserByName(String name){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < people.size(); i++){
        if(people.get(i).actualName.equals(name)){
            return people.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can remove them simply by doing:

`people.remove(getUserByName("Alex"));`

Comment: That would iterate twice through the list, instead of just once. And that's not what is being asked.

Comment: but it make sense when You use getUserByName(String) as reusable part of code (when you are searching to match user for given criteria)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Map where key would be a nickname. Then removing would look like

```
Map<String,User>myMap = new HashMap<String,User>();
myMap.put("username", new User(...)); 
myMap.remove("username")
```

Such approach gives better performace since reading Map is more efficient than iterating Array and it looks better in code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clue:

```
public void removeUser(String username){
    people.remove(username);
}
```

Here, `username` is a String. You are trying to remove a String from an ArrayList which contains only Users, not Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int addProduct(Product item)

{  

    int id = 0;

    stock.add(item);

    numberOfProducts++;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < stock.size(); i++)
    {

        if(stock.get(i).getID() == item.getID())
        {

           id++;

        }

        if(id > 1)

        {

            stock.remove(i);

            numberOfProducts--;

        }

    }

    return id;

}
```

This is great for fixing products or items with the same id!
If you have any questions about the var names search Project assignment "BlueJ" grade 12.

Comment: This code seems to be completely unrelated to the code in the question. How is this intended to be an answer?